# Javascript regex and replacing consecutive character sets

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm having a problem with replacing unnecessary character sets from a string. The following regex replaces the first occurrence of the character set "&=&" but doesn't take care of the leftovers. How does one replace the first and any consecutive occurences of a character set with regex?

```
var test = "var1=data1&var2=data2&=&=&=&=&var3=data3&=&=&var4=data4&var5=&var6=data6";
var result = "";
result = test.replace(/(\&\=\&)+/g, '&');

// Result returns "var1=data1&var2=data2&=&=&var3=data3&=&var4=data4&var5=&var6=data6"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a positive look-ahead instead. basically, look for `&=`, but only those followed by another `&`:

```
var a = "var1=data1&var2=data2&=&=&=&=&var3=data3&=&=&var4=data4&var5=&var6=data6";
var b = a.replace(/\&=(?=\&)/g,'');
// b = var1=data1&var2=data2&var3=data3&var4=data4&var5=&var6=data6
```

(Which I think is what you're after)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of (&=&)+, what you need is ([&=]+&)+

Comment: Great stuff, thanks. Although this regex doesn't account for variables with no value (e.g., `var5=&var6=data6` becomes `var5&var6=data6`, the equal sign will need to be left intact after var5).